# Nonempty interior is equivalent to the feasibility of set of strict quadratic inequalities. Why?

Tags: general-topology, decision-problems

From [Convex Optimization](http://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/):

> Let $E_i = \{x \mid f_i(x) \le 0\}$ where $f_i(x) = x^TA_ix + 2b_i^Tx +
>  c_i$ for $ i = 1, 2, \dots, m$ and $A_i \in S^n_{++}$ where $S^n_{++}$
>   is the set of all positive definite matrices.  We then ask when the
>   intersection of these ellipsoids has nonempty interior.  This is
>   equivalent to feasibility of the set of strict quadratic inequalities
>    $$f_i(x) = x^TA_ix + 2b_i^Tx + c_i \lt 0 \text{ for } i =1, 2, \dots,
>  m$$

I can see why the inequalities imply the interior because if $f_i(x) \lt 0$, then $f_i(x) \le 0$, but I'm having trouble showing the interior implies the inequalities.

If I start with assuming $\text{int}(\cap E_i) \neq \emptyset$.  Then there's an $x$ such that $f_i(x) \le 0$ for all $i$.  Assume that the set of inequalities is infeasible, therefore there's $i$ such that $f_i(x) \ge 0$.  If $f_i(x) \gt 0$ then I see the contradiction but if $f_i(x) =0$ I'm not sure how to proceed.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: There is only one system.  The question is asking why showing the intersection is nonempty is the same as showing feasibility of the system.

Answer (score 1):

The essence of the result is the following:

Suppose $x^*$ is an interior point of the
set $E= \{x | f(x) \le 0 \}$ where $f$ is convex and differentiable. Then either $f(x) = 0$ for
all $x \in E$ or $f(x^*) <0$.

In the above case, since the $A_i$ are positive definite, the $f_i$ can never be constant
on an open set.